# Angular/Datables server-side processing

Tags: angularjs, datatable, server-side

I am trying to implement DataTables server-side processing/pagination for a table in angularjs. I have used the DataTables example but my table does not show. I am pretty sure I am missing one slight thing but can't figure it out....tried many things....

My HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="consolidatedPageTable" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th >Source</th>
            <th >Mailing Date</th>
            <th >Status</th>
            <th >CPI</th>
            <th >User ID</th>
            <th >Program</th>
            <th >Customer Number</th>
            <th >Customer Name</th>
            <th >DL Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

My controller:

```
app.controller('ConsolidatedController', function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$filter,$location,$routeParams) {

    createTable();

    $location.path('consolidated');

});

function createTable(){
$(function(){
    var table = $('#consolidatedPageTable').dataTable({
        "destroy": true,    
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "scripts/consolidationTable.php",       
        "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [9],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": true
        }
    ]
    });
})
}
```

My php scipt (I replaced server specific information with XXX)

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$table = "consolidated";
$primaryKey = "customerNumber";
$columns = array();
$columns[] = array('db' => 'source' , 'dt' => 0);
$columns[] = array("db"=>"mailingDate","dt"=>1);
$columns[] = array("db"=>"status","dt"=>2);
$columns[] = array("db"=>"cpi","dt"=>3);
$columns[] = array("db"=>"userId","dt"=>4);
$columns[] = array("db"=>"shorttext","dt"=>5);
$columns[] = array("db"=>"customerNumber","dt"=>6);
$columns[] = array("db"=>"customerName","dt"=>7);
$columns[] = array("db"=>"dlDate","dt"=>8);
$sql_details = array("user" => "XXX","pass" => "XXX","db" => "XXX","host" => "XXX");
require("ssp.class.php");
echo json_encode(SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns ));
?>
```

I can run the php script by itself and it displays the correct data in the format shown in the dataTables example. In my application though, on the screen all I get is the header line and it does not appear to be in a dataTables looking format.

Can anyone see what could be causing no data to show?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive the "columnDefs" object should be an array:

[image]

I console logged this after using the DTColumnDefBuilder included in the angular-datatables package. I could be wrong - I am having some difficulty with DT as well.

Comment: Thanks. I think mine is though. I will try looking.